# How do I project a point stored as Lat / Lon to a state system?

Tags: postgresql, coordinate-system, postgis-2.0

I have some points stored as WGS84 (EPSG:4326) data. I want to write a SELECT statement to return the projected values, in EPSG:2811, and unprojected values.

Here is my table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE points (name varchar, point geometry);
```

Here is the SQL used to inserted the points:

```
INSERT INTO points(name, point) VALUES(2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(<lon> <lat>)', 4326));
```

This gives me a readable view of the imported data for a quick QA check:

```
SELECT name, ST_AsText(point) FROM points;
```

How do I add the transformed coordinates to my SELECT statement? I think I need to use ST_TRANSFORM but beyond that I'm lost.

Install details:

```
POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3924" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ST_Transform function has quite simple parameters: a geometry object and a target SRID. This should do it.

```
SELECT name, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,2811)) FROM points;
```

Comment: For future readers, you need to set the source SRID before the above works. `SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID(TableName, ColumnName, EPSG_ID);`

Comment: Right. Ideally that happens when the table is created.